# How to stop vim from reformatting lines inside a codeblock in a markdown file?

Tags: formatting, filetype-markdown

I keep the `a` formatoption in vim when I'm modifying markdown files, so my lines are automatically kept to `textwidth` characters long, with automatic reformatting when I modify text.

How can I make vim keep this behavior, but not reformat/join lines that are inside a triple-backtick code block? For example, consider the following file:

````
# Title

Here's some content that vim is automatically wrapping to 60
characters long, because I have run :set textwidth=60 and
:set formatoptions+=a. However, when I'm in the codeblock
below, I would like vim to stop the automatic wrapping as
well as the line joining.  As it stands, this file would be
impossible to reproduce in vim with my current settings.

```
def hello():
    print("Hello world")
```
````

Trying to type that codeblock at the end gives me:

````
``` def hello(): print("Hello world") ```
````

Is my style of markdown abnormal? Do people just rely on manually turning off the `a` formatoption when they're modifying a codeblock? Or am I missing an easy way of handling such codeblocks in markdown files?

I also recorded [this asciinema video](https://asciinema.org/a/eBYB6hmd4JsN2Oy3XZtbZZzOD) to illustrate the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Entering paste mode should stop autoformatting as well, though that's just swapping out one manual operation for another. One option might be to set a key mapping in insert mode to insert the three backticks and toggle paste mode or the `a` formatoption. I don't hard wrap markdown, personally, so this has never really occurred to me before, but I can't imagine there's a terribly elegant solution.

Comment: I have this problem too... Have not yet found a solution besides implementing the format myself in vimscript.